# PYTHON3 error:unrecognized arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to give a TXT file with argparse and then to open it in a function.
Can you tell me why it say  : error:unrecognized arguments : dataBase.txt
(ps: dataBase is the file I'm trying to open)

update(1)
my main :

```
if __name__ =='__main__':   

    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("file_name",type= argparse.FileType,help="name of file with network")

    args=parser.parse_args()
    z=args.file_name
    names,network= loadNetwork()
```

a little part of my function:

```
def loadNetwork(): 


    fileName=open('z', 'r')

    name = fileName.readlines()
```

Comment: How are you running your script?

Comment: Linux: 
python3 rumor.py dataBase.txt

Comment: Where exactly is the error (what line), and what does it read? (edit answer to add info)

Comment: Is dataBase.txt in your current directory?

Comment: I don't know. there are not a line .. it only says : error:unrecognized arguments

Comment: Yes dataBase.txt is in the same directory !

Comment: I cleaned up your indentation

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because `file` is not a valid type for argparse in Python3.  The `type` argument takes a callable, and since `file` doesn't exist in Python3, it'll throw an error.  Try using [FileType](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects) instead.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("file_name", type=argparse.FileType("r"), help="name of file with network")
```

Comment: I tried but the error is always there ..
(unrecognized arguments)

Comment: Could you update your question with your latest code? Also, try just taking in the `file_name` argument as a string.  From your original question, looks like you were trying to open the file twice.  Once when parsing arguments, and once in `loadNetwork`.

Comment: You need to instantiate the `FileType` object.  Lemme update my answer for an example.

Comment: I'm really sorry but how I can do this ? (it's my first post ..)

Comment: Try substituting the "add_argument()" line in my answer into your code. It shows how to instantiate a `FileType` object and use it in add_argument()

Answer (score 0):

Here's roughly, how I think your code should look:

```
def loadNetwork(afile): 
    name = afile.readlines()
    return name

if __name__ =='__main__':   
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("file",type= argparse.FileType('r'),
        help="name of file with network")

    # FileType opens the file you specified;
    # so you don't need to open it
    args = parser.parse_args()
    names,network = loadNetwork(args.file)
    args.file.close()
```

It's a good idea to pass values set by `argparse` to your functions as parameters, rather than setting global variables.

But if instead you would prefer to open and close the file yourself, I'd suggest:

```
def loadNetwork(filename): 
    with open(filename) as f:
        name = f.readlines()
    return name

if __name__ =='__main__':   
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("filename", help="name of file with network")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    names,network = loadNetwork(args.filename)
```

the `with` statement opens and closes the file.  A down side to this is that `argparse` isn't going to issue an error message if the filename isn't valid.  But the `with open` will.  Also this doesn't accept `'-'` as a filename (`FileType` takes that to mean `sys.stdin`).